# can't connect to any database after upgrading open-ssh

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, connection, openssh

I upgraded open ssh with this command: sudo apt-get upgrade openssh-server

I rebooted the server and after that, I can't connect to any database (Wordpress database, you'll database, phpmyadmin database)

for Wordpress I get: Error establishing a database connection

for yourls I get: Incorrect DB config, or could not connect to DB

for phpmyadmin I get: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

WHat's the solution please!

I think that it's a mysql problem because it doesn't not start and when I check mysql.service I find that's failed

WHat's the solution please!

This is logs:

[This is the error log /var/log/mysql/error.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFfly.png)

[error.log page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAsRT.png)

[mysql status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgEmj.png)

[systemctl status mysql.service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUrU2.png)

[journalctl -xe page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al9BX.png)

[journalctl -xe page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzi1v.png)

[journalctl -xe page 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qgSn.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can check MYSQL status by running following command

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql status`

Or restart and try once

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

If you still can not connect database you can change DB_HOST localhost to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: The status is failed and if i start or restart it's always failed. I add many logs at the first post to understand more the problem

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the solution was to go to:  etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
I found mysqld.cnf permission set to 644
I change it to 777 and the MySQL works again.
I don't know why running the upgrade with this command
sudo apt-get upgrade openssh-server
changed many permissions to files and directories.

I think that 777 is too open, can I make a less permission without stoping MySQL? what permission do you advise me to both mysqld.cnf and my.cnf in those directories?
etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
and
etc/mysql/my.cnf

Answer (score 0):

welcome,

Try the permission `640 (rw-r-----)`.  That's the minimal permission required.